# How React Native show amount of new messages badage around the buttom tab bar with Expo?

Tags: react-native

Do you know how to make a message notification on the react native buttom tab bar ,like this :

[image]

Thank you so much!!

Comment: I assuming you're using react navigation. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/#add-badges-to-icons

Comment: Oh Hi friend ,You are right !!! I have just checked , Yes ,there's somthing I am looking for ,THank you so much !!